# Query SQL com 2 subselects para query lambda (ou linq)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, expressões-lambda

```
select fieldA from TableA
where fieldA = 459249 and
fieldB in (
    select FieldC
    from TableB
    where FieldD in
    (
        select cte.FieldE
        from TableC cte
        where key= 'ABDC123'
    )
)
```

Consegui chegar até o ponto abaixo, o projeto não compila:

```
TableA.Where(x => x.FieldA == 459249)
   .Select(x => x.FieldA .Contains(TableB.Select(i => i.FieldB).Contains
   (
    TableC.Where(c => c.FieldC== "ABDC123").Select(c => c.FieldD).ToString()
   )
));
```

Comment: Não compila? Qual o erro de compilação?

Comment: O erro acontece aqui TableB.Select(i => i.FieldB).Contains. The type cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicity. Eu tentei tipar mas recebo a mensagem de erro "Cannot resolve method Contains (string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto porque `Select` traz um campo que não é exatamente um `IEnumerable`. `Contains` só existe pra `IEnumerable`s.

Em primeiro lugar, substitua os dois primeiros `Select` por `SelectMany` (que junta todos os elementos selecionados em um `IEnumerable`).

Procure não usar `Contains` fora do `Where`. Neste caso, `Intersect` funciona melhor.

```
TableA.Where(x => x.FieldA == 459249)
      .SelectMany(x => x.FieldA).Intersect(TableB
                  .SelectMany(i => i.FieldB)
                  .Intersect(TableC
                            .Where(c => c.FieldC == "ABDC123")
                            .Select(c => c.FieldD))
                  )
              );
```

Comment: .SelectMany(x => x.FieldA.Contains... x.FieldA.Contains nesta parte não aparece a opção .Contains tem somente algumas opções como ToString, CompareTo etc

Comment: Ah, sim. Perdão. Vou corrigir.

Comment: @TiagoCrizanto Veja agora.

Comment: Cara achei que esse ia funcionar. Deu problema novamente no segundo select (SelectMany). Erro: The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. Tentei tipar esse cara mas aí os erros vem como no primeiro select que fiz.

Comment: Faz sentido. `Contains` devolve `bool`. Troquei para `Intersect`.

Comment: You're the man! O projeto rodou... mas eu estou tendo um problema em tempo de execução quando executo esse cara. DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. Já foi de grande ajuda e vou continuar na luta! valew!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que dessa forma você possa conseguir:

```cs
var resultado = from tableA in TableA
join tableB in TableB on tableA.FieldB equals tableB.FieldC
join tableC in TableC on tableB.FieldD equals TableC.FieldE
where tableA.FieldA == 459249 && tableC.key = "ABDC123"
select tableA.FieldA;
```

*Obs.: Não consegui testar esse código ainda.*

Comment: Cara não deu porque já no primeiro select eu preciso verificar se já existem resultados na lista.